# Как изменить страницу "Нет подключения к сети"?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

У меня есть WebView приложение, и когда нет подключения к интернету, то отображается [это](https://i.ibb.co/n7r4hnc/Screenshot-20221013-220918.jpg).

Есть ли способ изменить эту старницу под себя?

UPD: Я использовал ответ ниже и вот какой код я получил (правильно я всё написал?):

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.pm.*;
import android.annotation.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.*;
import java.net.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://exemple.com");

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N) @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
            {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }
        };
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    if (url != null && (url.startsWith("http://")))
                    {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            {

                Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
                String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                requestPermissions(permissions, 1);
            }
        }

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength)
                {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    request.setDescription("Скачивание файла...");
                    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Скачивание началось", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

MyWebViewClient.java

```
import android.webkit.*;

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        if (error.getErrorCode() == WebViewClient.ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP) {
            String message = "Произошла ошибка " + error.getDescription();
            String html = "<html><body><b>" + message + "</b></body></html>";
            view.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Были какие-то у вас попытки? Приведите код. Пробовали ли переопределять `onReceivedError` и использовать метод `loadUrl` у webview (как в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37386138) ответе)?

Comment: Нет, я не понимаю как и где их использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы иметь возможность обрабатывать ошибки, необходимо создать свою реализацию класса `WebViewClient`.

Создаем класс `MyWebViewClient`, который наследуется от `WebViewClient`, и переопределяем метод [`onReceivedError`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceError)):

```java
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        if (error.getErrorCode() == WebViewClient.ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP) {
            String message = "Произошла ошибка " + error.getDescription();
            String html = "<html><body><b>" + message + "</b></body></html>";
            view.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        }
    }
}
```

В активити достаем `WebView` и устанавливаем ему `MyWebViewClient`:

```java
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
```

Теперь, если вай-фай и мобильные данные будут отключены, то будет возникать ошибка с кодом [`ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP). Эту ошибку мы обработали в своей реализации `WebViewClient`, и пользователю будет выведена страница html, которую мы задали.

Обратите внимание, если вы поддерживаете версии до Android 6 (ниже API 23), то вам необходимо аналогичным образом реализовать [второй](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) (устаревший) метод `onReceivedError`.

Comment: Попробовал этот метод, всё сделал как вы написали (наверное, возможно я что то не туда написал) но у меня всё равно отображается [эта](https://i.ibb.co/n7r4hnc/Screenshot-20221013-220918.jpg) ошибка, ничего не поменялось.

Comment: WebViewClient у WebView может быть только один. Соответственно, вызов `setWebViewClient` должен быть только один, а у вас их два. Объедините две реализации WebViewClient в одну.

Comment: А не подскажите, как вместо `String html = "<html><body><b>" + message + "</b></body></html>";` загрузить сам html файл из assets

Comment: Просто не получается подключить стили к эту html прямо здесь

Comment: Ну или хотя бы как оформлять эту старницу

Comment: В вашем вопросе не было сказано, что страницу нужно грузить из assets. Посмотрите в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37386138) ответе, там страница загружается из assets. Если возникнут трудности, задайте [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).